# Компилятор Си показывает ошибку, которой нет!

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc

Я писал заголовочный файл для Си, чтобы создать тип переменной bool (да я знаю, есть библиотека stdbool, но я хотел написать его сам)

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "bool.h"

int main()
{
    bool isBool true;
    
    if (isBool) printf("okay!\n");
    else printf("Not okay!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

bool.h

```
struct b_ool
{
    int true = 1;
    int false = 0;
};

typedef struct b_ool bool;
```

но компилятор и microsoft visual studio выдаёт:

**требуется точка с запятой. строка 6, столбец 17, файл main.c** (то есть, где *bool isBool true;*)

Но! Прошу заметить, там уже стоит точка с запятой. Подскажите пожалуйста, что делать?

Comment: Ошибки синтаксиса в каждой строке. Делайте `enum MyBool{ my_false, my_true };`  `enum MyBool isBool = my_true;`

Answer (score 2):

Что вы хотите этим сказать?

```
bool isBool true;
```

Как компилятор должен отреагировать на

```
int n 15;
```

по-вашему? Если `true` — это инициализирующее значение, напишите

```
bool isBool = true;
```

Comment: очень тупая глупость с моей стороны) спасибо

Comment: Это не глупость, это описка. А вот то, что вы бросились тут же спрашивать, не пытаясь самостоятельно разобраться — это уже несколько хуже...